# How to discern which image generated a particular feature map, while training CNNs?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Let's say I feed 3 grayscale images to a CNN, having a combined shape of 3,28,28. This process will generate multiple feature maps for each image. How do I identify which feature map corresponds to a particular image.

Here is some code -

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        print("Shape of x = ", x.shape)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        print("Shape of x = ", x.shape)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()

foo = torch.randn(3,1, 28, 28)

foo_cnn = net(foo)
```

For instance, the first convolution generated 6 feature maps from 3 images. Is there a way for me to identify which feature map belonged to which image, so that I can perform some operation on it.

Comment: *the first convolution generated 6 feature maps from 3 images*, you mean "3 feature maps"?

Comment: Nope, if you see the comment in the forward method, 6 feature maps are generated from 3 images -
      
```py
  x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
  print("Shape of x = ", x.shape)
  #Shape of x =  torch.Size([1, 6, 12, 12])
```

Comment: Each of the six filters inside your layer will convolve with the three images from your input, you can't determine which corresponds to which. In other words, each one of those six layers is a function of the three grayscale images.

Comment: @Ivan But he's not feeding 3 images into the model; that would require the input to be of the shape: ```(3, 1, 28, 28)``` for grayscale. What he's doing instead is (in a sense) concatenating the 3 images into the depth dimension resulting in the shape: ```(1, 3, 28, 28)```, thus the 6 output feature maps cannot be attributed to a specific image.

Comment: That is exactly what I said: *Each of the six filters inside your layer will convolve with the three images from your input*. The first layer has six filters, each having a kernel size of 5x5 and 3 channels total. And, that's also why I specifically ask that we describe the input as a 3-channel input (even if it's actually just a concatenation of three grayscales) instead of "3 images".

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Thank you for this information. This shouldn't be a problem. I can easily reshape my input to (3,1,28,28). Can we now discern which feature map generated the image?

Comment: @Ivan Thank you for this information. This shouldn't be a problem. I can easily reshape my input to (3,1,28,28). Can we now discern which feature map generated the image?

Comment: @desert_ranger Your original question was discerning which image generated which feature maps, and in that case; reshaping the input to ```(3, 1, 28, 28)``` and changing ```conv1``` to ```(1, 6, 5)``` will result in the following output: ```(3, 6, 12, 12)``` and hence, the ```1st``` 6 feature maps in the ```1st``` batch correspond to the first image in the batch, and the ```2nd``` 6 feature maps correspond to the ```2nd``` image in the batch and so on.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi I have made the edit. Thank you so much. If you write the answer, I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distinguish which image generated which convolved feature maps, one must split the different input images into the batches dimension (`#images=#batches`), such that when applying any convolutional layers, they're applied on each image separately, not a weighted sum of the different input images as would be the case if they were split into the channel/depth dimension.

Right now you're **not** feeding 3 images into the model (in pytorch's eyes); that would require the input to be of the shape: `(3, 1, 28, 28)` for grayscale images and `(3, 3, 28, 28)` for RGB images. What you're doing instead is (in a sense) concatenating the 3 images into the depth dimension resulting in the shape: `(1, 3, 28, 28)`, thus the 6 output feature maps cannot be attributed to a specific image (a weighted combination of the 3, since they're in depth dimension).

Therefore, reshaping the input to `(3, 1, 28, 28)` and changing `conv1` to `(1, 6, 5)` will result in the following output: `(3, 6, 12, 12)` and hence, the `1st` 6 feature maps in the `1st` batch (of the output) correspond to the first image in the batch (of the input), and the `2nd` 6 feature maps correspond to the `2nd` image in the batch and so on.